# Creating a middleware function to check if user role is equal to 'Admin'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

I'm creating a blog using the latest MEAN Stack technologies. A logged in user can create a new user with the roles 'admin' and 'moderator.

[Creating a new user with an admin role or moderator role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr5jL.png)

This route is protected and currently, only a logged in user can access it. Here is the middleware for checking if the user is authenticated or not.

```js
//check_auth.js

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token,  'my_jwt_secret');
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Auth failed!'});
  }


};
```

I apply this middleware to protect unauthorized access to some of my routes. I want to create a similar middleware in which I check if the user is an administrator or not. So I can apply this middleware on the route for creating users, so only an authorized user and a user who has the role of 'admin' can create a new user.

I think this can help in creating the middleware. When a user logs in the id, email, and role is stored in the jwt.

```js
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  let fetchedUser;
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      fetchedUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    })
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id, role: fetchedUser.role },
        "my_jwt_secret",
        { expiresIn: "1h" }
      );
      res.status(200).json({
        token: token,
        expiresIn: 3600
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    });
});
```

The whole code can be found in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/rajotam/Eleven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Route Handler to all endpoints that need verification and import it wherever needed.
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

ex.

```
router.post('/login', verify.isAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    //do something
})
```

//verify function in separate file

```
module.exports = {
    isAdmin: (req, res, next) =>{
        if(req.user.admin){
            next();
        }else{
            res.status(403).send();
        }
    }
}
```

Full code examples:

https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52

Comment: I know that I have to do it that way since I already created a middleware for check if the user is authenticated or not. I'm not sure how do I extract the role from the token and check if the user is an admin ?

Comment: I edited my answer with full code examples from medium.

Comment: @gbraide can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903540/finding-user-with-admin-role-as-true

Answer (score 0):

When you create token

```
const token = jwt.sign(
 { email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id, role: fetchedUser.role },
 "your_jwt_secret",
 { expiresIn: "1h" });
```

**email**, **userId** and **role** are appended with this token. Now you can use them when token decoded.

After apply middleware on routes to get authenticate user

```
 // You did this
 // jwt.verify(token,  'my_jwt_secret');
 // You need to store this into variable so that you can use them 
 // use them in going request.

 const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,  'your_jwt_secret');

    /*
     This decodedToken holds email, userId and role
     you can pass it to req
     req.userId = decodedToken.userId
     req.email = decodedToken.email
     req.role = decodedToken.role
     next()
    */
```

Only Important code is here which is try block

```
try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,  'my_jwt_secret');
    req.userId = decodedToken.userId
    req.email = decodedToken.email
    req.role = decodedToken.role
    next()
 }
```

In your route

```
router.post('/login', checkAuthMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
    //Now you have userId, role and email Id to use
    const userId = req.userId
    const role = req.role
    const email = req.email
   // Now you can separate user role here
   // Write some other logic here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.userData = { email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId, role: decodedToken.role};
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You are not authenticated!" });
  }
};
```