# finding user with admin role as true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on an e-commerce project and I only want to allow users with admin as true to be able to create and update products in the products collection(MongoDB database), but somehow I am getting it wrong because when I use a user with admin true token as a bearer token in authorization I receive the catch error

this is my user model code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        required:true,
        type:String
    },

    email:{
         type:String,
         unique:true,
         required:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:String
    },
    profilePic:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        default:'https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/46/83/96/360_F_346839683_6nAPzbhpSkIpb8pmAwufkC7c5eD7wYws.jpg'
    },
    admin:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true,
        default:false
    }
    
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

my Middleware code  for the protection for product creation

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import userModel from '../models/user.model.js'


export const productCreationProtection = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {

    let authorizationToken;

    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        try {
            authorizationToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]

            // decode user id
            const decode = jwt.verify(authorizationToken, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
            // Find the userModel and we use select to exclude password for find
            req.user = await userModel.findOne(decode.id).select('admin')
            next();

        } catch (error) {
            res.sendStatus(401)
            throw new Error("You're not authorized to performe this function")
        }

 
    }

    if(!authorizationToken){
        res.sendStatus(401)
        throw new Error("Not Authourized to performe this action")
    }
   
});
```

Comment: print `error` to console in your `catch` block

Comment: The error >> You're not authorized to perform this function. how can I validate so that only user with admin: true is the only one who can create products

Comment: Can you `console.log(error)` before `res.sendStatus(401)` line and share screenshot?

Comment: ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to findOne() must be an object, got 61f4f62338ff80c4103d3bba

Comment: @Dharmaraj please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70927598/not-authorized-but-admin-token-given-as-bearer-token

Comment: hi @Dharmaraj can you assist with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477946/data-is-returned-from-asynchronous-call-then-undefined-pops-up-in-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findOne` method takes an object as parameter but you are passing a string. If you are trying to find a user with given ID, then try refactoring your code as shown below:

```
req.user = await userModel.findOne({ _id: decode.id }).select('admin')

// Check if admin field is true
if (!req.user.admin) {
  return "Forbidden"
} 
next()
```

This will return document where `_id` is equal to `decode.id`. Do replace `_id` if you are querying based on any other field.

---

Alternatively, you can also add admin field in query itself:

```
const user = await userModel.findOne({ _id: decode.id, admin: true })
if (!user) {
  // User with given ID not found or is not an admin
  return "Forbidden"
}
next();
```

Comment: But how do I validate that if the user admin: true is the one responsible for product creation and update because either way if use a token of a user whose admin is false the request is still sent to the database

Comment: @MAXWELOCHIENG I thought you might have any validation in later stage of the code. But check my updated answer.

Comment: yeaa the first code worked so fine only user with admin: true can send request to server

Comment: sorry but I will tag you in another question because I am  trying to  run app.get() method to get a list of all the products in the database but I am getting an empty object

Comment: actually, no need I figured it out and it worked fine. thanks, Bruv